# Cambiar versión Angular 10 a 8 en Windows

Tags: angular, cmd, windows10

En un intento de arrancar ng serve en CMD Windows ha saltado esta excepción:

[image: Excepción no arranque módulo Angular]

Al comprobar la versión con ng --version se muestra que está en Angular 10.2.2

[image: Resultado ng --version]

Lo que necesito es hacer downgrade a la versión 8.2.14

Qué comando me permite a bajar de versión y poder ejecutar mi proyecto Angular sin problemas?

Muchas gracias de antemano! :)

Comment: No hay un comando para hacer run downgrade. ¿Estás seguro que actualizar el CLI a la 10 no es mejor que bajar la versión de tu proyecto?

Comment: @PabloLozano Muy buenos días. Es por temas de rendimiento y adaptar a los tutoriales que he encontrado. En un proyecto anterior funcionaba con Angular 8, y deseo aplicarlo al actual.

Comment: Pudiste chequear [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363530/how-to-downgrade-angular-cli-version/50363601) solución propuesta en soEn?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Si, hice los pasos, pero nada, lo siento. No me ha devuelto a la versión deseada.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a responder, al final he quedado con la versión actual de Angular 10.2.2 en el CMD de Windows. Hay un momento en el que no puedes bajar a versión 8 por la npm-cache del Roaming.